# Replacing items from a dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I have two data structures. I'd like to take numerical values from the first dict and replace values from a second dict with these numerical values.

The first list is

```
a = {'gender':['m', 'f', 'f'], 'age':['old', 'old', 'young']}
```

The second dict is

```
b = {'gender':{'m':0.9, 'f':0.1}, 'age':{'old':0.4, 'young':0.6}}
```

I want the final dict to look like this:

```
{'gender':['0.9', '0.1', '0.1'], 'age':['0.4', '0.4', '0.6']}
```

Comment: they are dicts not lists

Comment: Can you show us what you're tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you need to loop through the items in your first dictionary, and then for each item in an element’s list, get the corresponding value from the second dictionary. You can do this nicely using a combination of a dict- and a list comprehension:

```
>>> a = {'gender': ['m', 'f', 'f'], 'age': ['old', 'old', 'young']}
>>> b = {'gender': {'m': 0.9, 'f': 0.1}, 'age': {'old': 0.4, 'young': 0.6}}
>>> {k: [b[k][x] for x in v] for k, v in a.items()}
{'age': [0.4, 0.4, 0.6], 'gender': [0.9, 0.1, 0.1]}
```